# RBS Enabled Database Migration SharePoint 2010 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, sql-server-2012, rbs

How can we do migration of SharePoint 2010 to 2013 RBS enabled database. We are using SQL database Attach & Detach method.

With normal database we are able to do this. But RBS enabled database We don't have Idea. Please Suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps which you need to perform.

- Stop Content Db to use RBS and Move in all the Files inside the DB
  from Blob Folder.
- Verity that files are inside Sql DB by running query.
- Test by uploading file to Site and verify it stores in sql DB.
- backup and restore the DB to your new SharePoint 2013 environment.
- If its a classic mode web app in 2010 then convert it into Sp 2013
  Claims based web app.
- Test it.
- Configure the RBS on SharePoint 2013 Farm after upgrade. link to the
  planning for RBS :
  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748638.aspx

Another Method is:

- Backup-SPSite http://mysiteurl -path C:\MyBackupFile\mysitebackup.bak
- Note all the details about the site collection and site that will be
  needed in the next step and then delete the original site collection
  (that we just backed up) from Central Admin.  NOTE:  If it is the
  last site collection, you could also do a "Dismount-SPContentDatabase
  WSS_Content" to only dismount it.  If you do this, you don't need to
  delete or detach the content database from SQL Server.
- Run the following powershell script to create a new content database
  (with no RBS) and create a new site collection that is identical to
  the original.
- Before the restore, you may need to run

  Get-SPDeletedSite
     -webapplication http://mysiteurl | Remove-SPDeletedSite
- Delete or detach the original content database.  (backup as
  appropriate) Restore the site.

  Restore-SPSite http://mysiteurl
     -C:\MyBackupFile\mysitebackup.bak -force

[RBS Enabled Database Migration SharePoint 2010 to 2013](http://sharepoint-community.net/forum/topics/sharepoint-2010-to-2013-upgrade-migration-with-rbs)

also check this link for troubleshooting.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e1d9581-2b24-4a43-9c4f-eb8159eaa515/2010-to-2013-with-rbs-enabled-content-database?forum=sharepointadmin